# Powershell regexp

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to replace or insert parts of an UNC path using regex.

Example input:

```
\\\\PCSHARE\Homedrive\John Doe
```

Example output:

```
\\\\PCSHARE.mydomain.org\Homedrive\John Doe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
 "\\PCSHARE\Homedrive\John Doe" -replace '(?<=\\\\)(PCSHARE)', '$1.mydomain.org'
```

Edit after comment:

try:

```
"\\PCSHARE\Homedrive\John Doe" -replace '(?<=\\\\)(.[^\\]*)', '$&.mydomain.org'
```

Comment: Thank you this works great! I got one last qeustion, is there a way to set the pattern so that it will work with diffrent computernames? Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @PointerNullException edited my answer, It should work for any computer account name.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
PS> "\\PCSHARE\Homedrive\John Doe" -replace '^(\\\\[^\\]+)', '$1.mydomain.org'
```

An alternative that doesn't require regex (though in this case I do prefer the regex version):

```
PS> $unc = '\\PCSHARE\Homedrive\John Doe' -split '(\\)'
PS> $unc[4]+='.mydomain.org'
PS> -join $unc
```